# Failing to downgrade my kernel version Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, gpu, amd-gpu

I am trying to downgrade my kernel version, because I am having problems installing AMDGPU-PRO GPU drivers.
So I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and my kernel is:

```bash
$ uname -r
5.4.0-65-generic
```

I need kernel ver 5.4.0-54 so I am doing this:

```bash
$ sudo apt install linux-image-5.4.0-54-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-54-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-54-generic
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-5.4.0-54-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0-54.60).
linux-image-5.4.0-54-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0-54.60).
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-54-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0-54.60).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But afer doing all this, and rebooting the system, the `uname -r` command is still showing `5.4.0-65-generic` not version 54.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The question is not about *programming*, so it is **off-topic** on Stack Overflow. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: This would be a good question to ask on https://askubuntu.com/ (I believe there is a way to move a question from one SO site to another, perhaps a moderator could help out with that.)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can have several kernals installed but will generally use the newest one.

To boot from an alternate kernal that is installed: press shift during the first few seconds of booting up to show the GRUB menu, select 'advanced options for ubuntu', and then select an alternate kernal from the list shown.

Answer (score 0):

Then after you have booted into the new (or old) kernal, use dpkg to remove or apt remove the kernal you don't want.